# Un-ravel an numpy mgrid

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

Suppose I have a grid defined as follows:

```
x,y = np.mgrid[0:5:5j, 0:5:5j]
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554188/numpy-mgrid-shapely-for-linestring-coordinates), I can go to to a co-ordinate list by performing:

```
coords = np.vstack((x.ravel(),y.ravel())).T
```

How may I return to the x,y values from co-ordinates, for example:

```
x,y = foo(coords)
```

Comment: `x,y = coords.tolist()[0]`???

Comment: What is `coords` shape?  Compare its values with the original `x`,`y`.  What's `x.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even bother to print the `x,y`?

```
In [58]: x,y = np.mgrid[0:5:1j, 0:5:1j]
In [59]: x
Out[59]: array([[0.]])
In [60]: y
Out[60]: array([[0.]])
In [61]: coords = np.vstack((x.ravel(),y.ravel())).T
In [62]: coords
Out[62]: array([[0., 0.]])
```

With `1j`, it is generating **1** element in each dimension.  The 2 arrays are then (1,1) shape, and combined (1,2).

Let's make the arrays more interesting

```
In [63]: x,y = np.mgrid[0:5:1, 0:5:1]
In [64]: x
Out[64]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
In [65]: y
Out[65]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

These are (5,5).

```
In [66]: coords = np.vstack((x.ravel(),y.ravel())).T
In [67]: coords
Out[67]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 0],
       ...
       [4, 4]])
In [68]: _.shape
Out[68]: (25, 2)
```

Since you've joined them in columns, we can get `x` back by indexing; and since we've 'raveled' them, we can `reshape` back to the (5,5) with:

```
In [69]: coords[:,0].reshape(5,5)
Out[69]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Another way to join the 2 arrays:

```
In [70]: np.stack((x,y), axis=-1).shape
Out[70]: (5, 5, 2)
```

which can be reshaped to match `coords`:

```
In [71]: np.allclose(np.stack((x,y), axis=-1).reshape(-1,2), coords)
Out[71]: True
```

There are more reshaping games where those came from :)

`ravel` is just reshaping to 1d:

```
In [72]: np.allclose(x.ravel(), x.reshape(25))
Out[72]: True
```

So `reshape(5,5)` is the obvious un-ravel.